# Bound the eigenvalues of a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can the following be true? Where can I read more about this subject of eigenvalues of matrix linear combinations? Can it hold for certain dimensions of matrices? What theory should we look into?

**We are considering a matrix $A$ and some small perturbation to it, $B$**. Some opportune bound on the 2-norm of $B$ exists, i.e. $\| B\|_2 \leq b$. We are looking for the criterion for the perturbation to not destabilize $A$, and/or that $s(A+B)-B$ is stable for $s>1$ (have eigenvalues with negative real part).
We assume that $eig(A) \in \mathbb{C}^-$ (complex but with negative real part) and that $eig(A+B) \in \mathbb{C}^-$ (all matrices being square). This assumption itself may be restricting $B$'s bound.

We wish: Then for all $s>1$ we have that $$Re(eig(s(A+B) - B)) \leq Re(eig(A))$$
in the sense that the real part of each eigenvalue of $s(A+B)-B$ is smaller than the corresponding one of $A$ (ordering the eigenvalues from smallest to largest real part).

For a scalar equation it is obviously true, but that does not mean too much, though simulations look promising ... The interpretation would be that given the assumptions this linear combination moves the eigenvalues to a more stable location (stable as in linear ODEs).

---

Another way to frame the question would be to consider $eig(s(A + \frac{s-1}{s}B) = s \cdot eig(A + \frac{s-1}{s}B)$ vs. $A$ - given the assumptions we know that it holds for $s=1, s\to\infty$, but does it neccesarily hold between? Can the eigenvalues in some way move towards the origin? Can a bound on $\|B\|$ guarantee the nice behaviour?

---

An intuition we have comes from the fact that the eigenvalues of $A+B$ must be continuous in $B$ (even though possibly sensitive), since the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A+B$ is continuous in $B$, so a small $B$ should not move the eigenvalues of $A$ far enough to destabilize.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{C}^-$?

Comment: Complex numbers with negative real part.

Comment: There isn't any agreed ordering of complex eigenvalues. What do you mean by a corresponding eigenvalue?

Comment: Order them from smallest to largest real part.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Consider $A=\pmatrix{-1&2\\ -2&-1}$ and $A+B=\pmatrix{-2 &-12\\ 0&-2}$. Clearly all eigenvalues of $A$ and $A+B$ have negative real parts. However, as
$$
\frac{3}{2}(A+B)-B=\frac{1}{2}(A+B)+A=\pmatrix{-2&-4\\ -2&-2}
$$
is a real $2\times2$ matrix with a negative determinant, it has a real positive eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right. I realized that this is though not what we are really after, the matrix $B$ is some "small" perturbation and we would like to show that for e.g. a cartain bound on the norm of $B$ (relative to $A$'s norm) the properties I proposed hold. I will update the OP.